How do I log a hyperparameter in lightning?
how can I log a hyperparameter which is a string in the lightning module? I want to use this hpram to save my model:
def experiment_name(exp):
    ckp = ModelCheckpoint(
                dirpath=f"/content/aims_proj/saved_models/{exp}",
                filename="model-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}-{criterion}", #criterion is a strign hparam
                save_top_k=1,
                verbose=False,
                monitor="val_loss",
                mode="min"
                )

class BaseModel(L.LightningModule):


    def __init__(self, criterion, lr, max_iters, warmup):
        super().__init__()
        self.criterion = Loss(criterion)
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        self.log(f"criterion", criterion)

I tried as shown in the code block above. I just want the saved model to inclue the hyperpameter.
